# Acquia Dev Desktop Redirects to Live Site

Tags: 7, acquia-dev-desktop

I have a weird thing happening - I took a copy of my live site, and a dump of my database, and imported it into the Acquia Dev Desktop application to run a dev site locally. This site has worked in this manner in the past. However, when I do this now, visiting the local path (ex. localhost:8082) redirects to my live site out on the web. I believe it's something in the database, as running the code with a standard Acquia database works, but as soon as I swap in the database from my live site the redirect occurs.

Any ideas what could be causing this?? I don't have anything in rules or actions to redirect anything, and I don't know what else it would be.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem tody, and it turns out that the securepages module causes it. After disable that module, everythin works.

Though, don't forget to enable the module before going online.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually ended up solving this problem myself as well (forgot I posted it here). The culprit for me was the Mobile Tools module. It kept redirecting me to the locations in the settings (which happened to be my live site). Disabling the module fixed the issue.